# changing white and black color using HSV color space

Tags: c#, image-processing, colors, rgb, hsv

im converting the the RGB color image into HSV color space and Im change hue using a trackbar and converting back it to RGB values. this methord works fine and changes color excepts for white and black pixels. why is that?

```
 public static Color ColorFromHSV(double hue, double saturation, double value)
{
    int hi = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(hue / 60)) % 6;
    double f = hue / 60 - Math.Floor(hue / 60);

    value = value * 255;
    int v = Convert.ToInt32(value);
    int p = Convert.ToInt32(value * (1 - saturation));
    int q = Convert.ToInt32(value * (1 - f * saturation));
    int t = Convert.ToInt32(value * (1 - (1 - f) * saturation));

    if (hi == 0)
        return Color.FromArgb(255, v, t, p);
    else if (hi == 1)
        return Color.FromArgb(255, q, v, p);
    else if (hi == 2)
        return Color.FromArgb(255, p, v, t);
    else if (hi == 3)
        return Color.FromArgb(255, p, q, v);
    else if (hi == 4)
        return Color.FromArgb(255, t, p, v);
    else
        return Color.FromArgb(255, v, p, q);
}

public void convertToHSV(Color color, out double hue, out double saturation, out double value)
        {
            int max = Math.Max(color.R, Math.Max(color.G, color.B));
            int min = Math.Min(color.R, Math.Min(color.G, color.B));

            hue = color.GetHue();
            saturation = (max == 0) ? 0 : 1d - (1d * min / max);
            value = max / 255d;

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because white, gray, and black have no hue, so they don't change if their hue is changed.

Comment: Indeed: It's only the brightness that changes for black, white and grey. Saturation (could be thought of as strength of colour) is 0, hence hue (colour) has no effect.

Comment: saturation = (max == 0) ? 0 : 1d - (1d * min / max) what happening in this code?